# Modelling the distribution of race results in sports

Tags: distributions, games, density-estimation

Let's say I want to model the distribution of race results of an individual athlete, say on the 100 meter dash. What class of distribution would fit this data well? Although the distribution of race results might look normal, it will clearly be skewed, since it is much harder to improve on your personal best than it is to have a really bad result because you stumble or get hurt. Therefore the distribution will have a long tail towards the slow end.

Is there any literature on modelling such data?

Answer (score 0):

stackexchange is possibly not the best place to answer this question which is more an "open" discussion question rather than something with a "closed" solution.

My 50 cents:

In reality, modelling the distribution of race results means modelling $P(r|C)$ where $C$ represents the set of competitors (contestants).

I think that modelling the distribution of $t$ where $t$ is the time is possibly more "stable".

I suspect that the distribution of $P(r|C)$ varies a lot and flattens out (tends to become a uniform distribution) as the "gap" of the distributions of $t$ across contestants declines or the "overlap" of the distributions increases (if normal you can check out [this](http://www.rasch.org/rmt/rmt101r.htm)). I suspect that, as the competition progresses towards the finals, the overlap increases as the contestants become faster and more consistent.

Not sure about literature about $P(r|C)$ but Monte Carlo simulations could do the job.

Comment: Thanks, @IcannotFixThis. By race result, I actually meant the personal time, as if you were running on your own. I don't care about the ranking, just about the times. If you feel this is unclear, I can update the question.